# Name a cell using a formula

Tags: vba, excel

My goal is to name the top right cell in my `Range` using a formula.  Is that possible?

First I find the top right cell using:

```
Cells(Selection.Row, Selection.Columns.count + Selection.Column - 1)
```

But then how do I name it?  I tried using `.Select` and the below, but just got an error.

```
Selection.Name = "=""SectionActions_""&'Add Section'!D3"
```

Comment: Haha not a class assignment, just a project I'm working on.  I'm trying to build one part at a time, but if asking questions in part like this is frowned upon, I will stop.

I do promise that I search in every configuration I can think of for an answer prior to posting.  For this question here, I've been trying to solve it for 4 hours :(

Comment: Cells(Selection.Row, Selection.Columns.count + Selection.Column - 1).Name = "SectionActions_" & Worksheets("Add Section").Range("D3").Value

Comment: Seriously?!?!  This is just the same as your previous question, except with the string "AddSection" replaced by the string "SectionActions"!  Use either my answer, or the answer by @ThomasInzina (which you accepted as solving your problem), and all you have to do is change the strings to the appropriate new values.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
Dim rngTest As Range
rngTest = Range(Selection.Row, Selection.Columns.count + Selection.Column - 1)
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Hi", RefersTo:=rngTest
```

I would **HIGHLY** suggest not using `Select` and `Selections`, however. If at all possible, get the `Range` beforehand, figure out the top-right cell, then set a `Range` to just that cell. Use that `Range` as the `RefersTo:=` argument instead.

EDIT: I suggested you do that, but it's much easier if I just do it in my suggestion... Lazy me.